# Remove item from reference_catalog if it's UID is gone or purge broken reference_catalog in Plone

Tags: plone, linguaplone

I have the following situation with LinguaPlone

- I have pages a1-en, a1-fi an a1-sv
- a1-fi and a1-sv think a1-en is the canonical translation
- a1-en `isCanonical()` returns False
- This is because `isCanonical()` checks if there are "translation of" references for the current item
- a1-en is one unlucky page, as there is actually "translation of" reference, but it is a broken reference where the item pointed by UID reference is gone. (It checks only references by UID, not if the actual content item exists).

Now, I need to fix this situation somehow to make a1-en believe that it is canonical page again. I need to remove this one corrupted reference from the reference_catalog from "sourceUID" index which is being checked.

**Questions**

- Are there automatic ways to maintain reference_catalog and clear broken entries
- If not is what is the manual way to fix this one broken entry in reference_catalog

Comment: normally the manage_translations_form should allow to delete and re-assign translation references. this won't clean up the catalog but might also make your translations behave the way you excpect them to do.

Comment: It doesn't work because the canonical copy misthinks it is not canonical copy and does not give you the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
badCanonical = app.Plone.en.offering.restaurants
badCanonical.isCanonical()  # False - contains a corrupted translationOf link
badCanonical.getTranslations()   # Get list of what translations should exist
cat = app.Plone.reference_catalog
cat.getReferences(badCanonical, relationship="translationOf")  # Displays UID referring object not existing
# Delete forward relationships
for b in cat.getReferences(badCanonical, "translationOf"): cat._deleteReference(b)  
badCanonical.isCanonical()  # True - fixed
badCanonical.getTranslations() 

# Check that one of the translated versions still work
translated = app.Plone.sv["kalajoki-erbjuder"].restauranger
translated.isCanonical()
translated.getTranslations()
```